# MaterializeCSS valing-wrapper responsiveness not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, material-design, materialize

I am trying to align content in vertical and horizontal middle and also use [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) columns to have 100% width when the window is on a smaller device and split equally across the window on larger devices:

```
<div class="row valign-wrapper">
    <div class="col s12 l6">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 l6 valign">
        B
    </div>
</div>
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3e44zdq/)

Unfortunately on smaller devices it just stays split inline. Rather than dropping to a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unfortunately on smaller devices it just stays split inline. Rather
>   than dropping to a new line.

The reason is that the `.valign-wrapper` is styled using Flexbox and `flex-wrap` is not set. This means that `.valign-wrapper {flex-wrap: nowrap;}` by default `flex-wrap` value is `nowrap` , which means it will stays split inline and will cause `s12 l6` grid to not work.

To solve your issue what you need to do is to set the `flex-wrap` of `.valign-wrapper` to `{flex-wrap: wrap;}`

---

```css
.valign-wrapper {flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row valign-wrapper">
  <div class="col s12 l6">
     <img width="100%" src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg">
  </div>
  <div align="center" class="col s12 l6 valign">
     B
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: these images are not in line with a large screen.

Comment: @maxisme Forgot to add materializecss.. Please see my update answer.

Comment: Unfortunately still does not work. See how `B` is vertically aligned in my code snippet.

Comment: I see.. I have seen your code snippet and be able to fix the issue. Please see my updated answer. Hope it helps.